# Go unexpected string literal

Tags: string, go, literals

This is my code in Go and everything is right I guess....

```
package main

import(
"fmt"
"encoding/json"
"net/http"

)
type Payload struct {
    Stuff Data
}
type Data struct {
    Fruit Fruits
    Veggies Vegetables
}
type Fruits map[string]int
type Vegetables map[string]int


func serveRest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *httpRequest){
    response , err := getJsonResponse()
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.println(w, string(response))

}






func main(){

http.HandleFucn("/", serveRest)
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:1337",nil)
}


func getJsonResponse() ([]byte, error){

fruits := make(map[string]int)
fruits["Apples"] = 25
fruits["Oranges"] = 11

vegetables := make(map[string]int)
vegetables["Carrots"] = 21
vegetables["Peppers"] = 0

d := Data{fruits, vegetables}
p := Payload{d}

return json.MarshalIndent(p, "", "  ")

}
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
API_Sushant.go:31: syntax error: unexpected string literal, expecting semicolon or newline or }
```

Can anybody tell me whats the error plz ....

Comment: The error message you get isn't reproducible. Line 31 is one of the blank lines in the middle of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few minor typos in your example. After fixing those, your example ran for me without the `unexpected string literal` error. Also, if you want to write the JSON to the `http.ResponseWriter`, you should change `fmt.Println` to `fmt.Fprintln` as shown in part 2 below.

(1) Minor Typos

```
// Error 1: undefined: httpRequest
func serveRest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *httpRequest){
// Fixed:
func serveRest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

// Error 2: cannot refer to unexported name fmt.println
fmt.println(w, string(response))
// Fixed to remove error. Use Fprintln to write to 'w' http.ResponseWriter
fmt.Println(w, string(response))

// Error 3: undefined: http.HandleFucn
http.HandleFucn("/", serveRest)
// Fixed
http.HandleFunc("/", serveRest)
```

(2) Returning JSON in HTTP Response

Because `fmt.Println` writes to standard output and `fmt.Fprintln` writes to supplied io.Writer, to return the JSON in the HTTP response, use the following:

```
fmt.Fprintln(w, string(response))
```